# Usage related_name queryset with Django CMS plugin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Python 3

Django 1.9

Django-CMS 3.2.2

I have something like this:

models.py

```
class PluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class InlineModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    plugin_key = models.ForeignKey('PluginModel' related_name='breakpoints')
```

cms_plugins.py

```
class InlineModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InlineModel

class PluginModelPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PluginModel
    inlines = [InlineModelInline,]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(CarouselPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        print(instance.breakpoints.all()) #for simple debug
```

I add a few inlines then save. In edit, all inlines appear normal, but if I publish the page, only an empty list is returned. I understand what it's publication system fault, but how can I make it work?

Comment: Is it correct `context = super(CarouselPlugin, self)`?

Comment: It's funny, I got into the documentation to show you that this is true and accidentally found there corresponds to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need add

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.breakpoints = oldinstance.breakpoints.all()
```

to my PluginModel. http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.2.2/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. @atterratio's answer will only work for for many-to-many relationships:

```
class PluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for breakpoint in oldinstance.breakpoints.all():
            breakpoint.pk = None
            breakpoint.plugin_key = self
            breakpoint.save()
```

Comment: This code from documentation, not work for me, but my work, although I use ForeginKey. May be some change in Django, I use latest?

Comment: There are variation in implementation based on whether are using M2M or FK relationship. In your question you are using a FK, therefore the snippet I posted should work.

Comment: I tell U I use FK, and U code don't work for me, my work.